# How to get current clipboard content inside textarea automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a program to detect current clipboard data automatically. I tried this `window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` but didn't work.

Comment: as ar as I know, no browser allows you to access clipboard that easily - it has to do with privacy/security - it's only available on cut/copy/paste events according to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData)

Comment: Can you imagine if you visit a website with your browser and they access your clipboard automatically? Not good.